# Send Outlook Calendar Invitation PHP

Tags: php

The objective of the code is to send the appointment and block people calendar by using PHP.

I have two pages here:
test.php

```
    <?php
    include ("iCal.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>iCal Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

    //$firstname is the first name of target
    //$lastname is the last name of target
    //$email is the targets email address
    //$meeting_date is straight from a DATETIME mysql field and assumes UTC.
    //$meeting_name is the name of your meeting
    //$meeting_duretion is the duration of your meeting in seconds (3600 = 1 hour)
    $firstname = "John";
    $lastname = "Smith";
    $email = "kelvinfoodumb@gmail.com";
    $meeting_date = "2010-07-06 13:40:00"; //mysql format
    $meeting_name = "Hello";
    $meeting_duration = 3600;

    //returns true or false
    $result = sendIcalEmail($firstname,$lastname,$email,$meeting_date,$meeting_name,$meeting_duration);

    //display result
    if($result) {
        echo "Email sent successfully.";
    } else {
        echo "A problem occured sending email";
    }   

?>
</body>
</html>
```

iCal.php

```
    <?php

//$firstname is the first name of target
//$lastname is the last name of target
//$email is the targets email address
//$meeting_date is straight from a DATETIME mysql field and assumes UTC.
//$meeting_name is the name of your meeting
//$meeting_duretion is the duration of your meeting in seconds (3600 = 1 hour)

function sendIcalEmail($firstname,$lastname,$email,$meeting_date,$meeting_name,$meeting_duration) {

    $from_name = "My Name";
    $from_address = "myname@mydomain.com";
    $subject = "Meeting Booking"; //Doubles as email subject and meeting subject in calendar
    $meeting_description = "Here is a brief description of my meeting\n\n";
    $meeting_location = "My Office"; //Where will your meeting take place


    //Convert MYSQL datetime and construct iCal start, end and issue dates
    $meetingstamp = strtotime($meeting_date . " UTC");    
    $dtstart= gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z",$meetingstamp);
    $dtend= gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z",$meetingstamp+$meeting_duration);
    $todaystamp = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z");

    //Create unique identifier
    $cal_uid = date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."-".rand()."@mydomain.com";

    //Create Mime Boundry
    $mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".md5(time());

    //Create Email Headers
    $headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";

    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
    $headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";

    //Create Email Body (HTML)
    $message .= "--$mime_boundary\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";

    $message .= "<html>\n";
    $message .= "<body>\n";
    $message .= '<p>Dear '.$firstname.' '.$lastname.',</p>';
    $message .= '<p>Here is my HTML Email / Used for Meeting Description</p>';    
    $message .= "</body>\n";
    $message .= "</html>\n";
    $message .= "--$mime_boundary\n";

    //Create ICAL Content (Google rfc 2445 for details and examples of usage) 
    $ical =    'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:'.$from_address.'
DTSTART:'.$dtstart.'
DTEND:'.$dtend.'
LOCATION:'.$meeting_location.'
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
UID:'.$cal_uid.'
DTSTAMP:'.$todaystamp.'
DESCRIPTION:'.$meeting_description.'
SUMMARY:'.$subject.'
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR';   

    $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST;charset=utf-8\n';
    $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST\n';
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
    $message .= $ical;            

    //SEND MAIL
    $mail_sent = @mail( $email, $subject, $message, $headers );

    if($mail_sent)     {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }   

}


?>
```

But the ouput show error with

> A problem occured sending email

Comment: best way is to test the ical generated first. so download the file in browser or write it to a file and test it in your outlook.
if this works you can make a new question on how to send email with attachment

Comment: Remove the @ in front of the `mail()` function, you might get an actual error message telling you what's wrong instead of your own non-helpful error message.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the problem by my self. Topic Closed.

```
    <?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'xxx.xx.com';                       // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SetFrom('xx@xx.com', 'xx xxx');
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '';                   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '';               // SMTP password
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Port = 25;                                    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS
$mail->addAddress('kelvinfoodumb@gmail.com');  // Add a recipient
//$mail->addCC($manlv4);
//$mail->addBCC('kelvinfoodumb@gmail.com');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$location           = "Stardestroyer-013";
    $date               = '20151216';
    $startTime          = '0800';
    $endTime            = '0900';
    $subject            = 'Millennium Falcon';
    $desc               = 'This email is a reminder for you. Please accept!';

$organizer          = 'Darth Vader';

    $organizer_email    = 'hxxr@xx.com';   
    $participant_name_1 = 'Kelvin';
    $participant_email_1= 'xx@xx.com';

    $text = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n
    VERSION:2.0\r\n
    PRODID:-//Deathstar-mailer//theforce/NONSGML v1.0//EN\r\n
    METHOD:REQUEST\r\n
    BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n
    UID:" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . "example.com\r\n
    DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. gmdate('His') . "Z\r\n
    DTSTART:".$date."T".$startTime."00Z\r\n
    DTEND:".$date."T".$endTime."00Z\r\n
    SUMMARY:".$subject."\r\n
    ORGANIZER;CN=".$organizer.":mailto:".$organizer_email."\r\n
    LOCATION:".$location."\r\n
    DESCRIPTION:".$desc."\r\n
    ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN".$participant_name_1.";X-NUM-GUESTS=0:MAILTO:".$participant_email_1."\r\n
    END:VEVENT\r\n
    END:VCALENDAR\r\n";

$headers = "From: Sender\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type:text/calendar; Content-Disposition: inline; charset=utf-8;\r\n';
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n"; #EDIT: TYPO
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $desc; 
$mail->AltBody = $text; // in your case once more the $text string
$mail->Ical = $text; // ical format, in your case $text string


if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
?>
```

Comment: Does this only work with Outlook? Is there a way to be able to send a calendar invite regardless of which email provider a user has? Or allow for multiple email providers in the same function?

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
 function sendIcalEvent($from_name, $from_address, $to_name, $to_address, $startTime, $endTime, $subject, $description, $location)
{
$domain = 'exchangecore.com';

//Create Email Headers
$mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".MD5(TIME());

$headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
$headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";

//Create Email Body (HTML)
$message = "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= "<html>\n";
$message .= "<body>\n";
$message .= '<p>Dear '.$to_name.',</p>';
$message .= '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
$message .= "</body>\n";
$message .= "</html>\n";
$message .= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";

$ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
'TZID:Eastern Time' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
'DTSTART:20091101T020000' . "\r\n" .
'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETFROM:-0400' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETTO:-0500' . "\r\n" .
'TZNAME:EST' . "\r\n" .
'END:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
'DTSTART:20090301T020000' . "\r\n" .
'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETFROM:-0500' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETTO:-0400' . "\r\n" .
'TZNAME:EDST' . "\r\n" .
'END:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
'END:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .  
'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
'ORGANIZER;CN="'.$from_name.'":MAILTO:'.$from_address. "\r\n" .
'ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_name.'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_address. "\r\n" .
'LAST-MODIFIED:' . date("Ymd\TGis") . "\r\n" .
'UID:'.date("Ymd\TGis", strtotime($startTime)).rand()."@".$domain."\r\n" .
'DTSTAMP:'.date("Ymd\TGis"). "\r\n" .
'DTSTART;TZID="Eastern Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($startTime)). "\r\n" .
'DTEND;TZID="Eastern Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($endTime)). "\r\n" .
'TRANSP:OPAQUE'. "\r\n" .
'SEQUENCE:1'. "\r\n" .
'SUMMARY:' . $subject . "\r\n" .
'LOCATION:' . $location . "\r\n" .
'CLASS:PUBLIC'. "\r\n" .
'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
'TRIGGER:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
'DESCRIPTION:Reminder' . "\r\n" .
'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";
$message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST'."\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= $ical;

$mailsent = mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers);

return ($mailsent)?(true):(false);
}
```

Comment: You should add what you changed to "fix" the problem.

Comment: I posted only the code i use (and works) here. its a single function doing the job :-D

Comment: Hi @GeraldSchneider, i had tested the code, but it's like nothing happen when i trigger the page. do you mind to share how to make it work?

Comment: this answer is from [this page](https://www.exchangecore.com/blog/sending-outlookemail-calendar-events-php/)

Comment: So this code is working and is sending an invite. Couple of questions: 1. Does this work only for Outlook or also gmail and yahoo? 2. When I get the calendar invite, it doesn't actually allow me to accept the invite, it says "No response required"... I am on outlook BTW. Thank you.