# PHP PEAR MAIL, how do you send an Outlook calendar invite?

Tags: php, icalendar, pear-mail

I have spent most of today trying different approaches: none worked.

- I can send emails using PHP PEAR MAIL
- I can build .ics files
- I can attach files to PHP PEAR MAIL emails

.. what I don't know is:

How do I format the email so that email clients (Outlook/android/iphone)  treat it as a calendar invite (rather than a regular email with a .ics attachment)

Any pointers to a working example would be appreciated, I exhausted my google-foo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send Outlook Calendar Invitation PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282134/send-outlook-calendar-invitation-php)

Comment: Thank you, the first example worked as desired...

I'll now go and decode what he did differently!